# How can we manage our memory more effectively with RunDeck 3.4.1 and TomCat 9 on Windows Server 2016 to prevent locking and crashing?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, windows-server-2016, rundeck

We have a Windows Server 2016 vm with 8192 MB ram with six cores and running RunDeck 3.4.1 with TomCat 9 from the rundeck.war file.  Lately we've been seeing a couple issues crop up. First, RunDeck keeps user login sessions open well past the 30 minute idle limit in TomCat and Second, RunDeck does not respond or is extremely sluggish when the StandBy Memory leaves less than 400 MB of 'free memory' as if it never gets access to the StandBy Cache or queue or the priority is so low it can't get access to it. When a job fails, this problem gets even worse; but it also happens on successful jobs.  This is causing our server to become unresponsive multiple times a day and the only way so far to free it is to manually release sessions in TomCat and/or to reboot the server completely.  In the RunDeck Profile I have set the JVM to export RDECK_JVM="$RDECK_JVM -Xmx2048m -Xms512m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -server".

Comment: Might be a question for Super User at https://superuser.com/questions/

Answer (score 0):

Following the official documentation, those parameters (Xmx, Xms, and MaxMetaspaceSize) need to be defined in the `setenv.bat` file, [take a look](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/install/tomcat.html#installation-on-windows).